# Force all x-axis values to compare in scatterplot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot` for plot a scatterplot. The following code produces a scatterplot that does not match this request.

```
months = []
data = [...] #some data in list form

#skipping the 8th value since I don't want data to refer at this value
for i in [x for x in range(1, len(data) +2) if x != 8]:
    months.append(i)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.scatter(months,data)
plt.scatter([months[-1]],[data[-1]], color=['red'])

plt.title('Quantity scatterplot')
ax.set_xlabel('Months')
ax.set_ylabel('Quantities')
ax.legend(['Historical quantities','Forecasted quantity'], loc=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

While I would like to see all months (from 1 to 10) on x-axis

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to force all numbers between 1 and 10 to appear as ticklabels on the x axis is to use

```
ax.set_xticks(range(1,11))
```

For the more general case where axis limits are not determined beforehands you may get ticklabels at integer positions using a [`matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator).

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

where `1` is the number of which all ticks should be multiples of.

Comment: using a locator, while not as simple, would maintain the desired results in the case the axis limit change

Comment: Hi IOBE (congrats for your name ;) ), I have used your code but the following error has been displayed: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ticker'

Comment: That is correct. You need to `import matplotlib.ticker`. Something like `matplotlib.pyplot.ticker` does not exist.

Comment: Ok, now it works. Thank you and @PaulH for your help

Comment: A question en passant: why odds x-axis values have been omitted? In a previous version of my code (in which the cardinality of x-axis values was the same), they were all displayed

Comment: Assuming that you haven't changed the version of matplotlib in between, the most probable (but not only) reason would be that the figure size or axes margins are different ( i.e. now the axes may be smaller than before).